# How to use lambda in existing project ASP .Net Core?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I have a existing project and I want to add lambda in my project. I am new in aws and Asp Net Core. I have read the lambda document but that does not work for me.
Help me!

```
 public class LambdaFunction : Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction
{
    [Obsolete]
    protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseApiGateway();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? To call a lambda to do something from ASP, to use serverless functions for a part of your project, or something else completely? If you have tried to implement, please post your code so we can have a look and help

Comment: I want to use serverless function for a part of my project

Comment: Do you want to host your ASP.NET project on a lambda? If yes, then you need to setup either API Gateway or Application Load Balancer to invoke it. The code snippet you have here is an adapter for the API GW proxy input to be converted to a "http request". I recommend you read up on how lambda is invoked first.

Comment: sure thank you for you help